OpenOCD issue on MacBook using STM32VLDiscovery
I am new to STM32 programming and using STM32VLDiscovery board for my development on MacBook Air M1 running Ventura 13.5
Following this video, I am trying to setup debugging on VS Code using Cortex-Debug
My launch.json file looks like
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "executable": "./examples/stm32/f1/stm32vl-discovery/miniblink/miniblink.elf",
            "name": "Debug with OpenOCD",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "servertype": "openocd",
            "configFiles": [
                "/opt/homebrew/share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink.cfg",
                "/opt/homebrew/share/openocd/scripts/board/stm32vldiscovery.cfg"
            ],
            "searchDir": [],
            "runToEntryPoint": "main",
            "showDevDebugOutput": "raw"
        }
    ]
}

When I run "start debugging", I run into below issues
"configuration": {
    "cwd": "/Users/meetu/Downloads/libopencm/libopencm3-examples",
    "executable": "/Users/meetu/Downloads/libopencm/libopencm3-examples/examples/stm32/f1/stm32vl-discovery/miniblink/miniblink.elf",
    "name": "Debug with OpenOCD",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "cortex-debug",
    "servertype": "openocd",
    "configFiles": [
        "/opt/homebrew/share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink.cfg",
        "/opt/homebrew/share/openocd/scripts/board/stm32vldiscovery.cfg"
    ],
    "searchDir": [],
    "runToEntryPoint": "main",
    "showDevDebugOutput": "raw",
    "__configurationTarget": 6,
    "gdbServerConsolePort": 55878,
    "pvtAvoidPorts": [],
    "chainedConfigurations": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "debuggerArgs": [],
    "swoConfig": {
        "enabled": false,
        "decoders": [],
        "cpuFrequency": 0,
        "swoFrequency": 0,
        "source": "probe"
    },
    "rttConfig": {
        "enabled": false,
        "decoders": []
    },
    "graphConfig": [],
    "preLaunchCommands": [],
    "postLaunchCommands": [],
    "preAttachCommands": [],
    "postAttachCommands": [],
    "preRestartCommands": [],
    "postRestartCommands": [],
    "preResetCommands": [],
    "postResetCommands": [],
    "toolchainPrefix": "arm-none-eabi",
    "extensionPath": "/Users/meetu/.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.12.1",
    "registerUseNaturalFormat": true,
    "variableUseNaturalFormat": true,
    "pvtVersion": "1.12.1",
    "__sessionId": "097e8e61-381b-4665-93fb-9493ac77ce88",
    "pvtShowDevDebugOutput": "raw"
}
Reading symbols from arm-none-eabi-objdump --syms -C -h -w /Users/meetu/Downloads/libopencm/libopencm3-examples/examples/stm32/f1/stm32vl-discovery/miniblink/miniblink.elf
Reading symbols from arm-none-eabi-nm --defined-only -S -l -C -p /Users/meetu/Downloads/libopencm/libopencm3-examples/examples/stm32/f1/stm32vl-discovery/miniblink/miniblink.elf
Launching GDB: arm-none-eabi-gdb -q --interpreter=mi2
1-gdb-version
Launching gdb-server: openocd -c "gdb_port 50000" -c "tcl_port 50001" -c "telnet_port 50002" -s /Users/meetu/Downloads/libopencm/libopencm3-examples -f /Users/meetu/.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.12.1/support/openocd-helpers.tcl -f /opt/homebrew/share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink.cfg -f /opt/homebrew/share/openocd/scripts/board/stm32vldiscovery.cfg
    Please check TERMINAL tab (gdb-server) for output from openocd
OpenOCD: GDB Server Quit Unexpectedly. See gdb-server output in TERMINAL tab for more details.

and

Waiting for gdb server to start...[2024-11-28T16:22:29.508Z] SERVER CONSOLE DEBUG: onBackendConnect: gdb-server session connected. You can switch to "DEBUG CONSOLE" to see GDB interactions.
openocd -c "gdb_port 50000" -c "tcl_port 50001" -c "telnet_port 50002" -s /Users/meetu/Downloads/libopencm/libopencm3-examples -f /Users/meetu/.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.12.1/support/openocd-helpers.tcl -f /opt/homebrew/share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink.cfg -f /opt/homebrew/share/openocd/scripts/board/stm32vldiscovery.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
CDLiveWatchSetup
Warn : Interface already configured, ignoring
Error: already specified hl_layout stlink
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst

Info : Listening on port 50001 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 50002 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Error: open failed

[2024-11-28T16:22:29.549Z] SERVER CONSOLE DEBUG: onBackendConnect: gdb-server session closed
GDB server session ended. This terminal will be reused, waiting for next session to start...

However, when I run the openocd command with sudo it seems to work but running the command separately does not open the debug code window automatically as shown in the video.
libopencm3-examples % sudo openocd -c "gdb_port 50000" -c "tcl_port 50001" -c "telnet_port 50002" -s /Users/meetu/Downloads/libopencm/libopencm3-examples -f /Users/meetu/.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.12.1/support/openocd-helpers.tcl -f /opt/homebrew/share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink.cfg -f /opt/homebrew/share/openocd/scripts/board/stm32vldiscovery.cfg
Password:
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
CDLiveWatchSetup
Warn : Interface already configured, ignoring
Error: already specified hl_layout stlink
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst

Info : Listening on port 50001 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 50002 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : STLINK V1J13S0 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3744
Error: SRST error
Info : [stm32f1x.cpu] Cortex-M3 r1p1 processor detected
Info : [stm32f1x.cpu] target has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for stm32f1x.cpu on 50000
Info : Listening on port 50000 for gdb connections


Additional Info
libopencm3-examples % system_profiler SPUSBDataType
USB:

    USB 3.1 Bus:

      Host Controller Driver: AppleT8103USBXHCI

        Hub:

          Product ID: 0x8095
          Vendor ID: 0x1a86
          Version: 3.10
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/s
          Location ID: 0x01100000 / 1
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 100
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

             USB OPTICAL MOUSE:

              Product ID: 0x3825
              Version: 1.00
              Speed: Up to 1.5 Mb/s
              Location ID: 0x01140000 / 3
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 100
              Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

            STM32 STLink:

              Product ID: 0x3744
              Vendor ID: 0x0483  (STMicroelectronics)
              Version: 1.00
              Serial Number: 0ÿj?VG778"?C
              Speed: Up to 12 Mb/s
              Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
              Location ID: 0x01110000 / 2
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 100
              Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

    USB 3.1 Bus:

      Host Controller Driver: AppleT8103USBXHCI



If you can run with sudo, then it is file permission issue. Make the file executable for user meetu. The question has nothing to do with stm32.
